# Asp.Net MVC4: Determine Id of HtmlHelper Generated Form Input

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

If I created a textbox like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.FirstName)
```

Is there a way for me to know what the Id will be for this input?  A way for other controls or javascript to refer to this input?

I can tag it using the htmlAttributes parameter; however, I was hoping there was a more direct route.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question from my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

Extension

```
        public static MvcHtmlString GetFieldIdFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expres) 
        { 
            var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expres); 
            var inputFieldId = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName); 
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputFieldId); 
        }
```

Page

```
<textbox for="<%= Html.GetFieldIdFor(m => m.FirstName) %>">FirstName:</textbox >
```

Script

```
<script> $.function('<%= Html.GetFieldIdFor(m => m.FirstName) %>'); </script>
```